# How to get 4G data used from TP link 4G router with terminal?

Tags: linux, router

I'm using a TP Link 4G router Archer MR400 and my machine running on Linux. I wish to develop an app to display the 4G data used. In order to begin, I need to know how to get 4G data used from command line, terminal or script. Please, could you tell how to get 4G data used of the TP Link 4G router? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? The router may have a telnet interface.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use the telnet interface to get this data?

Comment: You could try an app like fing. That will scan for open ports.